# Python I/O cannot find file, but path seems OK

Tags: python, file-io, io

I am  with a python script. I want to open a file to retrieve data inside. I add the right path to `sys.path`:

```
 sys.path.append('F:\WORK\SIMILITUDE\ALGOCODE')
 sys.path.append('F:\WORK\SIMILITUDE\ALGOCODE\DTW')
```

More precisely, the file `file.txt` I will open is in DTW folder, and I also add upper folder ALGOCODE. Then, I have command

```
inputASTM170512 = open("file.txt","r")
```

I have this present:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
   inputASTM170512 = open("ASTM-170512.txt","r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ASTM-170512.txt'
```

Why? Do you have any idea?

Comment: As the answers point out, `sys.path` isn't used for opening arbitrary files. But you also should escape the backslashes in directory paths on Windows: `F:\\WORK\\SIMILITUDE\\ALGOCODE`; the backslash is an escape character itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`open()` checks only the current working directory and does not traverse your system path looking for the file.  Only `import` works with that mechanism.

You will either need to change your working directory before you open the file, with `os.chdir(PATH)` or to include the entire path when trying to open it.

Answer (score 4):

When you try to open file with `open`, for example:

```
open("ASTM-170512.txt","r")
```

you will try to open a file in the current directory.

It does not depend on `sys.path`. The `sys.path` variable is used when you try to import modules, but not when you open files.

You need to specify the full path to file in the `open` or change the current directory to the correspondent place (I think that the former is better).